# Why am I unable to push these results to an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

I'm trying to change

`results = $("x", xmlResponse).map(function() {`

to

`results.push = $("x", xmlResponse).map(function() {`

but doing so prevents any Autocomplete suggestions from appearing.

If I simply remove "push" again, the Autocomplete suggestions appear correctly with no issue.

How can I use results.push properly here?

Comment: What's "results" currently defined as? Try adding `var results = []` before the `.push`

Comment: ` var results = [];` is defined globally but the problem persists -- the Autocomplete suggestions don't appear if I use 'push'.

Comment: If `results` is `[]`, then `results.push` is a *method* - you are supposed to *call* it (`results.push(element)`), not *reassign* it (`results.push = element`). And that will probably not do what you want, since it will push the whole array you get from `map` as an element to `results`, not individual elements - for that, you would want `results.push.apply(results, arrayOfElements)`.

Comment: Is there a reason your wanting to go from = to push()?  Because results.slice(0, 5) is acting on an array.  And if you [].push($.map()) your array will have a single element, which is an array.  Your probably after [].concat($.map(...)) instead.

Comment: @Taplar The reason is that I am going to use another AJAX function right after, which is almost identical but "GetMovies" instead of "GetGames". Therefore, "results" must contain the combined results of both AJAX calls so that the Autocomplete will suggest both Movies and Games.

Comment: I think you want concat()

Comment: @Teli _"The reason is that I am going to use another AJAX function right after, which is almost identical but "GetMovies" instead of "GetGames""_ Can include second AJAX function at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 I have now updated the post to include the second function. Thank you

Comment: @Taplar Is there something wrong with my syntax here?  http://pastebin.com/JYMa7Dwp `results.concat( $("Game", xmlResponse).map(function() {
                    return {
                        value: $("GameTitle", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("ReleaseDate", this).text()) || "(unknown date)")
                    };
                }) );    `

Comment: Someone mentioned below, $.fn.map (which is what your using since your doing map off of a lookup) returns a jQuery object containing the result set.  To get a basic array do get() off of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.get()` to return an array from `.map()`

```
results = $("Game", xmlResponse).map(function() {
    return {
        value: $("GameTitle", this).text() 
               + ", " 
               + ($.trim($("ReleaseDate", this).text()) || "(unknown date)")
    };
}).get()
```

Comment: What might be the proper syntax for .get() in the GetMovie function? I'm trying `results = $.map(list, function(v,i){
                    return {
                        label: v.Title + ' (' + v.Year + ')',
                        value: v.Title
                    };
                }).get()` but I get the error "TypeError $.map(...) is not a function"

Comment: `.get()` is not necessary if use `$.map()`

Answer (score 1):

`push` is a method, not a `property` .

You can't use it as a property.

```
results.push = $("Game", xmlResponse).map(function() {
```

In order to `push` element into `results` , `results` have to be an array

Like this

```
var results =[];
results.push("your things");
```